# Firefox Linux problem

Tags: firefox

Firefox – Linux – Kubuntu Problem

All mouse over text boxes are black. This occurs on all menu bar, bookmark tool bar, status bar 
and history icons and bookmarks. This started a few weeks ago. No major changes to hardware
oe software.

I have searched and found no solution. In desperation I did a 'reset'  and reinstall. Now I have a plain vinalla version using the default theme and no addons or customizations. The info in the text boxes is still blacked out.  I also have Chromium browser which does not have this problem. This is a dual boot desktop PC. I can boot Win 7 and Firefox and the text boxes display text.

I prefer Linux and Firefox 'was' my prefered browser. I now need a couple of hours to get FF back 
to the way it was. Reset wipped out all my addons and themes and other customizations, so clearly
none of these were causing this problem. In this process I found that FF is now disabling addons that lack some kind of 'signing', for my 'protection, of course! Very anoying.

So no point in re customizing FF unless someone can offer a solution. Basically it's just plain 
broken.

Firefox 46.0.1   Ubuntu 14.04   Kernel 3.13-0-87

Comment: This problem is caused by a bad interaction between recent Firefox versions and the Oxygen GTK3 theme, so it has nothing to do with your firefox settings. Nothing we can do but wait for a fix.

Comment: There is no fix to date. FF on Linux is toast!